# install docker-compose (1.8.0-2)

Tags: docker

I am using ubuntu 17.04 on a virtualbox .
I need to install docker-compose (1.8.0-2),using command line .
Here https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/docker-compose I do not see any instructions for that.Can anyone please help me out.

I tried this:

[image]

Comment: `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install docker-compose`?

Comment: edwinksl:thats not working either

Comment: "Not working" contains no information. This is the correct way to install the package. What happens when you run these commands? Post the output to your question if you want an answer.

Comment: Pilot6: I have updated my question.

Comment: Please don't post terminal output as a screenshot. Post it as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`universe` repository is not enabled for some reason.

Go to System Settings -> Software & Updates and enable it there.

In the command-line you can enable it by

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then you will be able to install it by

```
sudo apt install docker-compose
```